# make it easier to call often used terminal commands

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, alias, path

I have a java tool that I use quite often from the command line but to use it I have to type `java -jar dsim.jar`. I want to make it so that I can call it just by typing `dsim` regardless of what directory I am in, but I can't quite work out how to accomplish this.

I have created a file at `~/.bash_profile` and put into it:

```
alias dsim='java -jar dsim.jar'
```

And I have placed the dsim.jar file into `/usr/local/bin` as I read this is where user created command line tools should be kept. This location is in my $PATH.

I think the alias works well but location of the file doesn't seem to be accessible from anywhere. If I call `dsim` from within `/usr/local/bin` it works fine but if I am in any other directory I get:

```
Error: Unable to access jar file dsim.jar
```

How can I get this to work from any directory?

Answer (score 5):

Use absolute paths for the jar file:

```
alias dsim='java -jar /path/to/dsim.jar'
```

Comment: That will probably work but isn't the idea of putting something into a directory in your PATH that you don't have to address it like that? I thought that having it in the PATH meant that you could call just the filename from any directory and it would be found?

Comment: @Sam Not for files like this. `java` is located using the PATH, but files are not, otherwise if you had a file called java in a folder then running a command such as `cp java java2` would copy the file from your PATH rather than the file in the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but you can consider the following solution as an useful one for often repeated commands:

> Create ~/.inputrc and fill it with this:
>
> ```
> "\e[A": history-search-backward
> "\e[B": history-search-forward
> set show-all-if-ambiguous on
> set completion-ignore-case on
> ```
>
> This allows you to search through your history using the up and down arrows … i.e. type "cd /" and press the up arrow and you'll search through everything in your history that starts with "cd /".

(via https://coderwall.com/p/oqtj8w)